# Mount USB 3.0 SD-CardReader in Ubuntu Guest (vbox)

Tags: 16.04, usb, virtualbox, sd-card

I'm running an Ubuntu 16.04. Guest on a Windows 10 Host Machine and want to mount a SD-Card on the guest machine via a SD-CardReader (USB 3.0).
The system detects the CardReader as "Generic Storage USB" and I enabled the USB 3.0-Controller in VBox. I already add my user to the vboxuser group and when I select the CardReader in VBox there appear no error.

But my problem is that I can't see my SD-Card in Ubuntu and I don't know how to deal with it after hours of research.

Further I can give you information about some commands:

```
## lsusb ##

-no output-

##lsblk##
NAME MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT  
sr0     11:0    1 55,3M  0 rom  /media/dominikr/VBox_GAs_5.2.8  
sda      8:0    0 87,9G  0 disk   
├─sda2   8:2    0    1K  0 part   
├─sda5   8:5    0    4G  0 part   
└─sda1   8:1    0 83,9G  0 part /

##lspci##
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation 440FX - 82441FX PMC [Natoma] (rev 02)  
00:01.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 82371SB PIIX3 ISA [Natoma/Triton II]  
00:01.1 IDE interface: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 IDE (rev 01)  
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Graphics Adapter  
00:03.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)  
00:04.0 System peripheral: InnoTek Systemberatung GmbH VirtualBox Guest Service  
00:05.0 Multimedia audio controller: Intel Corporation 82801AA AC'97 Audio Controller (rev 01)  
00:06.0 USB controller: Apple Inc. KeyLargo/Intrepid USB  
00:07.0 Bridge: Intel Corporation 82371AB/EB/MB PIIX4 ACPI (rev 08)  
00:0a.0 Ethernet controller: Intel Corporation 82540EM Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 02)  
00:0b.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 82801FB/FBM/FR/FW/FRW (ICH6 Family) USB2 EHCI Controller  
00:0d.0 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 82801HM/HEM (ICH8M/ICH8M-E) SATA Controller [AHCI mode] (rev 02)
```

There is an entry when I type `"dmesg"`, that the `ehci_hcd/xhci_hcd init failed`. Maybe this information could be helpful? 
Anyway is there another way in VBox to work with a SD-Card in Ubuntu (as guest machine)?

Comment: Do you really need to pass through the USB device or would it be enough to access the SD card content through the host system via shared storage? I'm not even sure if VirtualBox can forward USB 3.0 yet.

Comment: I need an access to the SD card for configuring a bootable sd card. You think there's a way to deal with a USB 2.0 CardReader?

Comment: What's the output of `lsusb`? If it doesn't list the drive and you already installed Guest Additions it's an issue with host system configuration?

Comment: no output of lsusb and the command "df -h" does not list the drive at all. I tried it with a usb 3.0-drive, but it occurs the same problem.
Vbox does list the drive and I can select it but I can not find it and the system does not list it in the terminal

Comment: yes I already installed it. 
what about the error: ehci_hcd/xhci_hcd init failed? I think that the drivers did not load right

Comment: Could you please add the entire verbatim error message plus surrounding lines if related into your question? Thanks.